# Remove white space from mysql data

Tags: php

When I get some data from my database and output it to my html table, I get some "?" at the end of the data.

Example

```
echo "<td>" . $row['data'] . "</td>";
```

gives

```
John Data��
```

So, how to remove the funny "��"?

Comment: how about your page's encoding?

Comment: +1 for *how to remove the funny"��"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trim white spaces in PHP:

```
echo "<td>" . trim($row['data']) . "</td>";
```

But I think it's more of an encoding problem.

Comment: echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['data']) . "</td>"; work thanks

Answer (score 3):

trim() is for whitespace.
The funny"��" is an encoding-problem.
Try utf8_decode or utf8_encode function on $row['data'].